# Exclude a framework in Debug builds with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have two frameworks (Amplitude and Sentry) which increase my app's build time by about 10x. I'd like to speed up builds by excluding them when the app is built for debugging, but can't seem to find a way to do this.

If it's relevant, I'm including these frameworks via SPM.

Comment: Did you try creating a target for debug and adding it's dependencies?

Comment: That does work, thanks. Not quite what I'm after as it requires managing two targets, but a decent workaround for now.